# Is it ok to return a stack object for a CString and why /GR causes undefined behavior to dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++, casting, cstring

I have polymorphic classes and I want to convert an object via `dynamic_cast<B>(A)` although with compiler optimization /GR I receive a message that it may cause undefined behavior. I'm using `static_cast` instead, but it does no run-time checks and is unsafe for my classes. Also is it valid to return a stack `CString` object from a class?

```
CString CKingdomWar::GetTeamName( eUserTeam eTeam )
{
    if( eTeam == ELDAR )
        return CString( "Eldar" );
    else if( eTeam == ELWYN )
        return CString( "Elwyn" );
    else if( eTeam == NORGNAGON )
        return CString( "Norgnagon" );

    return CString( " " );
}
```

Comment: You're not returning a stack-based CString. You return by value, a copy will be created (in theory, RVO will probably kick in though). It's fine,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already commented, your CString is returned by value and it's not a problem.

Regarding the static/dynamic casting, you should show the specific code that gives the warning.  You don't normally get such warnings if you use `dynamic_cast` correctly (that is, to convert pointers or references between compatible types).

If `dynamic_cast<B>(A)` is to work, then A and B should both be a pointer or reference to an object in the same inheritance tree.  For instance, if you had:

```
class A {
    // ...
};

class B : public A {
    // ...
};

A* inst = new B;
```

Then `dynamic_cast<B*>(inst)` is okay.  Same deal with references.  If `inst` is not of type B then the pointer version will return NULL, or the reference version will throw an exception.

However, you can't do this:

```
A inst;
B nonono = dynamic_cast<B>(inst);
```

Comment: Very great, but could I do B nonono = static_cast<B>(inst); ?